# How to make child elements overflow horizontally if the parent's overflow-x is set to hidden

Tags: html, css

Assume that the main content container should be rigid but the child div's can have the ability to overflow within themselves while not exceeding the maximum available width.

```css
main{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.table_container{
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="table_container" >
      <table></table>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve it. Run the snippet below and enjoy :)

```css
main > section {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #afafaf;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.table_container { 
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: forestgreen;
  color: #fff;
  width: auto;
  height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="table_container" >
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et fermentum dui. Ut orci quam, ornare sed lorem sed, hendrerit auctor dolor. Nulla viverra, nibh quis ultrices malesuada, ligula ipsum vulputate diam, aliquam egestas nibh ante vel dui. Sed in tellus interdum eros vulputate placerat sed non enim. Pellentesque eget justo porttitor urna dictum fermentum.
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Okay. Let me test it out. Thanks

Comment: It worked. Thanks